# When I use -fopenmp in workthread and got a segmentation fault. What is wrong?

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, openmp

I'm trying transplant a excited code to a Android device and the code used OpenMP technology. SO I write a demo to verify that OpenMP is supported on my device. This device equipped with Android 6.1 system and with ARMv7a architecture.

My demo is as followed and I compile it with Android NDK r10d.The demo run normally in main thread, but get a segmentation fault and core dumped in work thread(NewThread1). What is wrong?

I had compiled and run this demo on PC device, ererything is OK! How strange!

I'm a beginner of OpenMP, someone can help me?

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <omp.h>

void* NewThread1(void* arg)
{
 #pragma omp parallel for
 //#pragma omp critical
        for(int iiii=0;iiii < 4; iiii++) {
  int a=11;
  int b=22;
  int c = a+b;
 }
}

int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
        #pragma omp parallel
 printf( "Hello world!\n");
  
 size_t size = 0;
 pthread_t new_thread_id;
 printf("Main thread id is %d \n",pthread_self());
 if(!pthread_create(&new_thread_id, NULL, NewThread1, NULL))
 {
  printf("create thread succeed!\n");
 }
 else
 {
  printf("Fail to Create Thread");
 }
 pthread_join(new_thread_id, NULL);
 
        return 0;
}
```

This is my compile script with Android NDK r10d.

```html
SET g++=f:\SoftWare\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10d\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe
SET CXX_FLAGS=-fPIE -pie -fopenmp
SET SYSROOT=f:\SoftWare\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10d\platforms\android-17\arch-arm
SET STL=f:\SoftWare\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10d\sources\cxx-stl\stlport\libs\armeabi-v7a\libstlport_shared.so

%g++% --sysroot=%SYSROOT% %CXX_FLAGS% -l%STL% -o helloworld helloworld.cpp
```

Comment: Can you try that without mixing OpenMP and pthread? While that may be fine on some platforms with some implementations, I wouldn't consider that to be very portable - or something an OpenMP beginner should be attempting.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had fixed this problem already. I compile the demo with Android NDK r10e and everything is OK. Thus it can be seen that there is a bug in Android NDK r10d when mixing OpenMP and pthread.

Comment: Don't assume a bug in the Android NDK just because you no longer get a segfault. You could still have undefined behavior, but it doesn't manifest in the same way. Stay careful.